# R *** caught segfault *** address 0x6, cause 'memory not mapped'

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to run a R code which involving package cubature (to find double integrals) and keep getting some unusual error.

When I tried the code in my Mac it worked (I used part of the data, the original dataset consists 1000 data points) but when I used the hpc it is ended up with following error after taking several hours. I tried to fixed it, but I could not.Do you have any suggestions?

*** caught segfault ***

```
address 0x6, cause 'memory not mapped'
Traceback:
 1: adaptIntegrate(f, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(Inf, Inf))
 2: mlogl(parameter, G)
 3: fn(par, ...)
 4: (function (par) fn(par, ...))(c(2.4565444712109, 4.35486392713201, 2.68167413499423, 3.99358777739855, 0.427859342210118))
 5: optim(c(alpha.start, alpha_0.start, v1.start, v2.start, rho.start),     logsum, R = R, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(eps, eps, eps,         eps, eps - 1), upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 1 - eps))
 6: mle(W, p_r)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
/var/spool/slurmd/job8915586/slurm_script: line 14: 24219 Segmentation fault      Rscript Program/part1.R
```

Comment: a quick google tells me this might be a memory problem.

Comment: Thank you @bob1. Still I couldn't find a way to fix this error.

Comment: @bob1 When you say memory error, you mean not enough memory? Or accessing a wrong part of the memory?

Comment: @F.Privé - no idea, this was a while ago, and it looks like there are a few possible causes - I think packages issues (remove and reinstall), or not enough RAM. I'm also not really a computer person, I just dabble in R occasionally, so it has me stumped.